# How to re-arrange the content in browser view using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

i can display the text in browser view as per the element placement. But i want to move the content in the browser view as per the Manuscript.

**XML Code**

```
<publicationMeta level="unit" position="60" type="article" status="forIssue">
..
..
<correspondenceTo>...</correspondenceTo>
....
..
</publicationMeta>
<contentMeta>
<titleGroup>
    <title type="main">.........</title>
</titleGroup>
    <creators>
    <creator creatorRole="author" xml:id="cr1" affiliationRef="#aff-1">
        <personName>
            <givenNames>.....</givenNames> 
            <familyName>..</familyName>
        </personName>
    </creator>
</creators>
<affiliationGroup>
    <affiliation xml:id="aff-1">.....</affiliation>
</affiliationGroup>
<abstractGroup>
    <abstract type="main" xml:lang="en">
        <p>...</p>
    </abstract>
</abstractGroup>
</contentMeta>
```

this is the XSLT template code for elements

```
<xsl:template match="correspondenceTo"><a name="{@xml:id}"/><p><span style="color:#FF6633" title="corresp"> <b>Correspondence To:</b>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;</span><xsl:apply-templates/></p></xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="affiliation"><br/><a name="{@xml:id}" style="color:#817339" title="Affiliation"/><sup><xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(@xml:id, '-'))"/></sup><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="contentMeta/titleGroup/title"><h1 title="Article Title"><xsl:apply-templates/></h1></xsl:template>
```

*Actually, it's viewing*

> **correspondenceTo:.................** Title
>
> Authors
>
> Affiliations
>
> Abstract

*it should viewed like this*

> Title
>
> Authors
>
> Affiliations
>
> **correspondenceTo:.................**
>
> Abstract

How can i re-arrange the text in browser view?
Could you please?

Comment: You will have to modify the template for the parent tag of `<correspondenceTo>` to change the order.

Comment: sorry, i could not understand. now i have edited the post for you quick reference.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the additional information. Looking at the XML I think we even have to ascend even higher in the node hierarchy. We need to find the common ancestor tag of `<publicationMeta>` and `<contentMeta>`.